# how to remove duplicates from a json defaultdict?

Tags: json, python-3.6, defaultdict

(Re-post with accurate data sample)

I have a json dictionary where each value in turn is a defaultdict as follows:

"Parent_Key_A": [{"a": 1.0, "b": 2.0}, {"a": 5.1, "c": 10}, {"b": 20.3,  "a": 1.0}]
I am trying to remove both duplicate keys and values so that each element of the json has unique values. So for the above example, I am looking for output something like this:

"Parent_Key_A": {"a":[1.0,5.1], "b":[2.0,20.3], "c":[10]}
Then I need to write this output to a json file. I tried using set to handle duplicates but set is not json serializable.

Any suggestions on how to handle this?

Comment: Why not just edit the *old* post to have the accurate data sample?

Comment: I actually deleted the older post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution using `itertools.chain()` and `itertools.groupby()` functions:

```
import itertools, json

input_d = { "Parent_Key_A": [{"a": 1.0, "b": 2.0}, {"a": 5.1, "c": 10}, {"b": 20.3, "a": 1.0}] }    

items = itertools.chain.from_iterable(list(d.items()) for d in input_d["Parent_Key_A"])
# dict comprehension (updated syntax here)
input_d["Parent_Key_A"] = { k:[i[1] for i in sorted(set(g))] 
                           for k,g in itertools.groupby(sorted(items), key=lambda x: x[0]) }   
print(input_d)
```

The output:

```
{'Parent_Key_A': {'a': [1.0, 5.1], 'b': [2.0, 20.3], 'c': [10]}}
```

---

Printing to json file:

```
json.dump(input_d, open('output.json', 'w+'), indent=4)
```

---

`output.json` contents:

```
{
    "Parent_Key_A": {
        "a": [
            1.0,
            5.1
        ],
        "c": [
            10
        ],
        "b": [
            2.0,
            20.3
        ]
    }
}
```